# javascript push jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some inline jquery what I want to load in the footer after the jquery is loaded.

I do not want to load the jquery in the header. And I do not want to change the inline jquery to a js file because there is also PHP in it.

But I do believe it is possible with javascript to load it in the footer.

In the header you do

```
var code = [];
```

So now you have an empty array.

And now I want to push the inline jQuery code in the array.

```
$(function myFunction(){
    // jQuery methods...
});
```

So eventually you can do something like this:

```
code.push(myFunction);
```

So that I can push all the different jQuery functions and when I put the push code in the footer it will be loaded.

But this does not work for me. The console log says that "myFunction" is not defined...

Comment: You can have `function myFunction(){
    // jQuery methods...
}` then `$(myFunction);` and `code.push(myFunction);`

Comment: try to define function like `function myFunction(){ // code }`

Comment: Please share sample html and js

Comment: I still don't get the purpose of pushing a function refrence in an array??? Do you mean in footer then to call `for (var i = 0, z = code.length; i< z; i++) code[i]();` ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you can do it like this:

```
var code = [];

function _dom_ready() {
    $(function() {
        // do something here...
    })
}

code.push(_dom_ready);
```

Or something like this:

```
function click_something() {
    $('div.something').click(function() {
        // event handler here
    });
}

code.push(click_something);

function click_handler_something2() {
    // event handler here
}

function click_something2() {
    $('div.something2').click(click_handler_something2);
}

code.push(click_something2);
```

Then run all the functions:

```
for(var f = 0; f < code.length; f++) {
    if(typeof code[f] == 'function') {
        code[f]();
    }
}
```

Comment: I understood it like this too but just be aware [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: @A.Wolff Didn't knew that one. Thanks. I'll correct my loop statement.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $(function myFunction(){
>     // jQuery methods...
> });
> ```

Here you have a function **expression** which you are passing as an argument to `$`.

Consequently:

- It will be called on the DOM Ready event (because `$(a_function)` is shorthand for `$(document).on('ready', a_function)`.
- It creates a variable called `myFunction` inside the scope of that function.

`code.push(myFunction);` will work, but only inside `myFunction`, and you probably don't want it there as it will get pushed onto the array repeatedly every time you call it.

You need a function declaration to make the function appear in the *current* scope.

```
function myFunction(){
    // jQuery methods...
}

code.push(myFunction);
$(myFunction);
```